# Unable to declare UnsignedInt data type for sending data model to server in dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to define `UnsignedInt? id` in my data model. But it keeps giving me this error when I am trying to send the model to the server.

> [SEVERE] json_serializable:json_serializable on lib/src/model/otp.dart
> (cached):
>
> Could not generate `fromJson` code for `countryID`. To support the
> type `UnsignedInt` you can:
>
> - Use `JsonConverter`   https://pub.dev/documentation/json_annotation/latest/json_annotation/JsonConverter-class.html
> - Use `JsonKey` fields `fromJson` and `toJson`   https://pub.dev/documentation/json_annotation/latest/json_annotation/JsonKey/fromJson.html
>   https://pub.dev/documentation/json_annotation/latest/json_annotation/JsonKey/toJson.html
>   package:myapp/src/model/otp.dart:18:16    ╷ 18 │   UnsignedInt?
>   countryID;    │                ^^^^^^^^^    ╵ [SEVERE] Failed after
>   103ms pub finished with exit code 1

Here is my code where I want to send the model to server:

```
Future<OTP?> getCode(String countryCode, String phone) async {
    const url = HttpUtils.baseUrl + HttpUtils.getcode;
    _myOtp = null;
    try {
      final response = await http.post(
        Uri.parse(url),
        headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"},
        body: json.encode(OTP(phoneNo: phone,).toJson()),
      );
      _myOtp = OTP.fromJson(json.decode(response.body)["otp"]);
    } catch (error) {
      if (kDebugMode) {
        print(error.toString());
      }
    }
    return _myOtp;
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UnsignedInt` is not supported.

> Out of the box, json_serializable supports many common types in the dart:core library: BigInt, bool, DateTime, double, Duration, Enum, int, Iterable, List, Map, num, Object, Set, String, Uri

See [json_serializable](https://pub.dev/packages/json_serializable) for details.